# Extracting data from JSON array with swift Codable

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable, decodable

I have a JSON response like this:

[image]

I have currently designed my decodable struct to be as follows:

```
    struct PortfolioResponseModel: Decodable {
    var dataset: Dataset

    struct Dataset: Decodable {
        var data: Array<PortfolioData> //I cannot use [Any] here...

        struct PortfolioData: Decodable {
            //how to extract this data ?
        }
    }
   }
```

The question is, how do I extract the data inside the array, which can have a value Double or String.

Here is the sample string to make this work on playground:

```
   let myJSONArray =
   """
   {
   "dataset": {
   "data": [
    [
   "2018-01-19",
   181.29
   ],
   [
   "2018-01-18",
   179.8
   ],
   [
   "2018-01-17",
   177.6
   ],
   [
   "2018-01-16",
   178.39
   ]
   ]
   }
   }
   """
```

Extracting the data:

```
do {
    let details2: PortfolioResponseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(PortfolioResponseModel.self, from: myJSONArray.data(using: .utf8)!)
    //print(details2) 
    //print(details2.dataset.data[0]) //somehow get "2018-01-19"

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I cannot use [Any] here.

Never use `Any` when decoding JSON because usually you do know the type of the contents.

To decode an array you have to use an `unkeyedContainer` and decode the values in series

```
struct PortfolioResponseModel: Decodable {
    var dataset: Dataset

    struct Dataset: Decodable {
        var data: [PortfolioData]

        struct PortfolioData: Decodable {
            let date : String
            let value : Double

            init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
                date = try container.decode(String.self)
                value = try container.decode(Double.self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can even decode the date strings as `Date`

```
struct PortfolioData: Decodable {
    let date : Date
    let value : Double

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        date = try container.decode(Date.self)
        value = try container.decode(Double.self)
    }
}
```

if you add a date formatter to the decoder

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
let details2 = try decoder.decode(PortfolioResponseModel.self, from: Data(myJSONArray.utf8))
```

Comment: That works !! Thanks. Though I still don't understand how that init(from decoder: ) really works... Also, can this solution be scaled-up, as in, if the inner arrays were to contain lets say 5 items (3 String and 2 Double), can the init func be updated to handle this as well ?

Comment: `init(from decoder: )` is a custom initializer where you can provide your own pattern to decode the passed object.  `unkeyedContainer` is the only way to decode nested arrays. Of course the solution can be scaled-up, just add properties and decoding lines accordingly. The values are decoded in the *order of appearance*.

Comment: "The values are decoded in the order of appearance..." Cool, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

To add to this, there is a very good example of complex JSON parsing with arrays in particular [here](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/). I hope this helps those who are trying to use Codeable with larger, more realistic JSON data.

The overview is this: Imagine you had the following JSON format:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "total_pages": 4,
        "per_page": 10,
        "total_records": 38
    },
    "breweries": [
        {
            "id": 1234,
            "name": "Saint Arnold"
        },
        {
            "id": 52892,
            "name": "Buffalo Bayou"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a common format with the array nested inside. You could create a struct that encapsulates the entire response, accommodating arrays for the "breweries" key, similar to what you were asking above:

```
struct PagedBreweries : Codable {
    struct Meta : Codable {
        let page: Int
        let totalPages: Int
        let perPage: Int
        let totalRecords: Int
        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case page
            case totalPages = "total_pages"
            case perPage = "per_page"
            case totalRecords = "total_records"
        }
    }

    struct Brewery : Codable {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
    }

    let meta: Meta
    let breweries: [Brewery]
}
```