# How to parse array of strings in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, parsing

I am writing a simple full stack app and I made the return from the backend to be, in certain cases, just like an array of strings like below:

```
["one","two","three"]
```

The problem I am having now is that this return can't be parsed in swift like usual JSON data. I searched but found nothing. What I am trying to do is :

`let json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.mutableContainers, .allowFragments]) as? [String]`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all
How can I parse this just like a normal array?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I am adding some more relevant code below:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in {
            do {
                let json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.mutableContainers, .allowFragments]) as? [String]
                print(json)
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
 }
datatask.resume()
```

The error I am getting in the console is "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}"

Thanks for all of you.

Comment: Show more relevant code. Where does `data` come from? What is the actual value you are trying to parse?

Comment: Have a look here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354401/extracting-data-from-json-array-with-swift-codable/48354582?noredirect=1#comment83696112_48354582

Comment: I've added more info in the post, please look again.

Comment: @vadian The console then yells at me complaining that the json return is neither an array nor a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting the *3840 error*, then the JSON is not valid JSON, period.

The JSON string equivalent of the array is supposed to be

```
let jsonString = "[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]"
```

The Swift 4 literal multiline syntax shows the actual format without the escaping backslashes

```
let jsonString = """
["one","two","three"]
"""
```

You are able to parse it without any options (**no .allowFragments**, and **no .mutableContainers**)

```
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String]
    print(array) // ["one", "two", "three"]
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Almost everybody misuses the JSONSerialization Reading Options

- *.allowFragments* is only needed if the root object is **not** array and **not** dictionary
- *.mutableContainers* is completely meaningless in Swift

In 99% of the cases you can omit the `options` parameter

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea what's that equivalent to in php as I did try to test the return using postman and it seemed fine?

Comment: The php equivalent is `$array = array('one', 'two','three');`

Comment: This is what I do!
I use `array_push($array, $row->Name)` where $row is `$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)`

Comment: Please create a string `let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)` before the `JSONSerialization` line and print and post that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give proper JSON response as data. After that, JSON serialisation will work properly. Your JSON response should be like this:

```
{
  "array": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ]
}

let json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.mutableContainers, .allowFragments]) as? [String]
                print(json)
```

After that in above line you will your array response like this one - http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=eafd7ff34b45b2a380ebbe5959607906

Update ####

Your response starts with array and it contains dictionary see below code for your example

```
    let jsonString = """
[{"Name":"one"},{"Name":"two"},{"Name":"three"}]
"""

if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
{
    let json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [.mutableContainers, .allowFragments]) as? [[String:String]]
    print(json)
}
```

Comment: I would do that but it doesn't work also for example I have tried a return of :

`[{"Name":"one"},{"Name":"two"},{"Name":"three"}]`

But still couldn't parse it as `[Dictionary<String,String>]`